# how to get the value from new textbox i added in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've added a new textbox to my grid view, and bound it, but I want to get the data out of new the textbox , because it's not bound.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            column_value = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(10).Text
next
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `TemplateField` `Cells.Text` is empty. You have to use `FindControl` to get the refernce to the control:

```
Dim column_values As New List(Of String)  
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("TextBoxID"), TextBox)
    column_values.Add(txt.Text)
Next
```

Replace `TextBoxID` with the correct ID of your `TextBox`.

Note that i've used a `List(Of String)` since a `GridView` normally contains multiple rows.